# How to select links from a list of links which are giving some kind of error?

Tags: python, hyperlink, request

I have a list of links. Many of them are giving errors like 404: page note found and many are not getting connected ie timeout error. They might give all different kinds of error, I have not checked all. I want to separate good links which are working and bad links which give any kind of error.
I tried to filter out the connection timed out links like this:

```
import requests
r=requests.get("http://www.carillionplc.co.uk/sustain/f_con2.htm", timeout=10)
```

But I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     79     if err is not None:
---> 80         raise err
     81 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address, socket_options)
     69                 sock.bind(source_address)
---> 70             sock.connect(sa)
     71             return sock

timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectTimeoutError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    353         else:
--> 354             conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    355 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1228         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1229         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1230 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1274             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1275         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1276 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1223             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1224         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1225 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1015         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1016         self.send(msg)
   1017 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py in send(self, data)
    955             if self.auto_open:
--> 956                 self.connect()
    957             else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    180     def connect(self):
--> 181         conn = self._new_conn()
    182         self._prepare_conn(conn)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    163                 self, "Connection to %s timed out. (connect timeout=%s)" %
--> 164                 (self.host, self.timeout))
    165 

ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7c86c14ba8>, 'Connection to www.carillionplc.co.uk timed out. (connect timeout=10)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    398         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 399             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    400 

MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.carillionplc.co.uk', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /sustain/f_con2.htm (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7c86c14ba8>, 'Connection to www.carillionplc.co.uk timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectTimeout                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-425ceeca52ad> in <module>
      1 import requests
----> 2 r=requests.get("http://www.carillionplc.co.uk/sustain/f_con2.htm", timeout=10)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    502                 # TODO: Remove this in 3.0.0: see #2811
    503                 if not isinstance(e.reason, NewConnectionError):
--> 504                     raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
    505 
    506             if isinstance(e.reason, ResponseError):

ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.carillionplc.co.uk', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /sustain/f_con2.htm (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7c86c14ba8>, 'Connection to www.carillionplc.co.uk timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))
```

Is there a simple way to just filter out the working links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know which links are working unless you try them.
So, if you required to filter broken links you can try this:

```py
import requests

links = [...] #your links are stored here
working_links = [] #empty list

for link in links:
  try:
    r=requests.get(link, timeout=10)
    working_links.append(link)
  except Exception as e:
    print(f'request to {link} failed with {str(e)}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can pass the requests into `try/except` statement, and remove the ones that reach the `except` statement from your list..

It would look something like the following:

```
for link in your_list:
    try:
        r = requests.get(link, timeout=1)
    except:
        your_list.remove(link)
```

Comment: Please note that changing the list you're iterating on is almost always a bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev In such case, adding a new list in the try statement as you mentioned is the answer..

Comment: But since it is a list of strings then I guess it won't be a problem at all..

Comment: please check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/7353524. The nature of elements stored in the list does not seem to solve the problem

Comment: That's right .. this will modify the indices as we go.. thank you for raising my attention to this.